# Is it possible for a RabbitMQ consumer to consume millions of empty messages that are not visible in the RabbitMQ management UI?

Tags: go, rabbitmq

I have a consumer written in go which consumes messages from several RabbitMQ queues.

The code looks like this:

```
queues := []string{"foo", "bar", "baz", "qux"}
for _, queue := range queues {
    go func(queue string) {
        var channel *amqp.Channel
        var notifyClose chan *amqp.Error
        for {
            channel, notifyClose = rabbit.DeclareChannel()
            channel.Qos(
                1,    // prefetch count
                0,    // prefetch size
                true, // global
            )
            rabbit.DeclareQueue(channel, queue)
            messages, err := channel.Consume(
                queue, // queue
                queue, // consumer - set the same as queue
                true,  // auto-ack
                false, // exclusive
                false, // no-local
                false, // no-wait
                nil,   // args
            )
            // read from messages in a continous loop 
        Loop:
            for {
                select {
                case err = <-notifyClose: // listen for RabbitMQ channel errors
                    break Loop // re-establish the channel - have to use label for break from loop, not from case
                case msg := <-messages:
                    log.Info("Received message", zap.String("queue", queue), zap.String("message", string(msg.Body)))
                }
            }
        }
    }(queue)
}
```

Now everything works well for all the customers using this app, except for one that can't use the RabbitMQ server shipped together with this consumer, and instead uses its own server part of a PaaS.

They have set up two consumer nodes, and every day (sometimes multiple times per day) both nodes start consuming millions of empty messages from some of the queue. Things are really strange because:

- both nodes start consuming the empty messages at the exact same time
- it happens only on some queues, and it seems arbitrary (now on `foo` and `bar`, next time on `bar` and `qux`, the third time on `foo`, `bar`, and `baz` etc.); both nodes consume from the same queues when they go crazy
- no messages are shown in the RabbitMQ management UI, except the good ones (with a body that isn't empty); these messages are "stuck" there, because the nodes are busy consuming empty messages
- to momentarily fix it, RabbitMQ server should be restarted (this fixes both nodes when they reconnect) OR each node should be restarted; if only one node is restarted, that one will not consume any empty messages, but the other will until it's also restarted
- the same problem doesn't happen for other customers that use other RabbitMQ servers

The issue here is that this customer doesn't have access to RabbitMQ's logs, and can only access the management UI. From their perspective, their server is functioning correctly and the problem happens somewhere in the consumer nodes. And I don't know how to go forward with this matter. I searched all over for a similar problem and no-one seems to have had it.

Comment: which RabbitMQ client library are you using?

Comment: amqp091-go => github.com/rabbitmq/amqp091-go

Comment: How do you handle when a consumer loses the connection with the RabbitMQ broker? Do you have code for handling broken conenctions?

Comment: @EminLaletovic I'm using `channel.NotifyClose()` to declare the go channel where mq channel or connection exceptions are sent. I've updated the initial post with it.